# Load event isn't working in Google chrome

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm just learning about load event handler and when I run the code in Google chrome it doesn't work can someone tell me why and how I can fix

---

it. By the way as u can see I want the alert function to execute as soon as everything is loaded thanks

This is my code below

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>

<title>Button</title>

<meta charset="utf-8">

<style>

body{

display:grid;

height:100vh;

}

h2{

margin:auto;

}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<h2>experiment</h2>

<script>

var exp =document.querySelector("h2");

function fun(){

alert("is it a success?");

}

exp.addEventListener("load", fun);

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `load` event is basically for `window` object. Try this snippet `window.addEventListener("load", fun);`. ... [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event)

Answer (score 1):

**Use DOMContentLoaded instead**

> The DOMContentLoaded event will trigger earlier and is usually
> considered the better option.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fun);
```

> [the load event] should be used only to detect a fully-loaded page. It
> is a common mistake to use load where DOMContentLoaded would be more
> appropriate.

***If you must use the load event***
If you must use the load event, you can add a listener to window instead:

```
window.addEventListener('load', fun);
```